# Rest API in Go (Consume and host)

Tags: api, rest, go

I am trying to request something, like a book by its id, and then host it locally so that if I write my local URL, like `http://localhost:8080​/books?books=<book-id>` it would show me the specific result.

To try to be concrete, I need to connect the two. Get the information from that URL, so "consume" and also host it locally, specifically by ID. I am not sure how to do both at once.

To create the paths, I've been using gorilla mux

So separately, I've used this, which would give me all the books at once (URL is not real).

```golang
func main() {
    response, err := http.Get("https://bookibook.herokuapp.com/books/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("there is no book with this ID %s\n", err)
    } else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }
}
```

and then this, which would create a local path for http://localhost:8080/books/ID

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func getID(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Get id %s\n", vars["id"])
}

func main() {
    // Configure routes.
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/books/{id}/", getID).Methods(http.MethodGet)

    // Start HTTP server.
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `if err != nil { fmt.Printf("there is no book with this ID %s\n", err) }` is probably a lie. This means there's a network error, not that you got a 404 response.  To check of "no book with this ID", you need to check the HTTP Response code.